# SGDClassifier fit and partial_fit functions

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, bigdata, algorithms

I wanted to know what is the correct way to train the SGDClassier model on new data observations? Should I use the `fit` function or the `partial_fit` function? How are they different?

Answer (score 4):

`fit()`, always initializes the parameters like a new object, and trains the model with the dataset passed in `fit()` method.

Whereas `partial_fit()`, works on top of the initialize parameter and tries to  improve the existing weights with the new dataset passed in `partial_fit()`.

It is always good to save the model in persistent storage (say pickle file), for later use or for further training.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a "correct way" with those options. Both will fit your data, but one will try to do it in one instance (`fit`) and the other will let you fit portions of your data (`partial_fit`).

In most cases, users will divide their huge dataset into smaller 'chunks' and feed these chunks in sequence to `partial_fit`, and the call to `partial_fit` with your final chunk will return the complete fit.